# What are those little numbers when I extract pitch in Praat?

Tags: prosody, praat

If I extract pitch in praat all those little numbers show up! What are those values standing for?

[little numbers and pink lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnBoo.png) (1263x665, 172 KB)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the 'Pitch help' button in the object window when the Pitch object is selected. I'm going to simplify this answer a bit:

Pitch estimation is inexact, so those numbers are basically the ranked candidates for pitch (y-axis, marked in Hz at intervals of 100 Hz) at that point in time (x-axis, marked in seconds).

If you zoom in a little, you'll see they're stacked vertically, with the best candidate  (highest integer) highlighted in pink.

The 'pink lines' are actually patterns of the best candidates. Pitch cannot be estimated for unvoiced portions, so you'll see those intervals marked in blue across the bottom ('Unv').

Comment: So if the number is "2" it means that there are 2 "???" at the same time and energy. But what is "it" that is at the same time and energy?

Comment: @mateuz the digit represents a "goodness value" on a scale of 0 to 9. According to Praat's algorithms, a candidate labeled '9' is more likely to be at the correct frequency than one labeled '4', for example.