# Why are f0 candidates stacked vertically in all .pitch files in Praat, like this one?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, prosody, praat

[image]

Why is it that, if I zoom into a .pitch file in Praat, the little numbers (pitch candidates) that are displayed are stacked into vertical lines?

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of your own question http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/8577/what-are-those-little-numbers-when-i-extract-pitch-in-praat.

Comment: But this time I'm asking about why the numbers are stacked horizontally. I tried to keep questions as focused as possible!

Comment: It would be best just to ask for a little clarification from the answerer in that question.

Comment: How it is different from the original question is unclear as it's worded. You mention _vertical_ lines in the body of the question, and it's not clear what "stacked horizontally" means, and it's not clear if it's a "what" question (seeking to understand the identity of something) or a "why" question (seeking to understand the reason for something).

Comment: *facepalm* sorry. mine english be rusty.

Comment: OK, I've taken the liberty of rewording the text to ask one specific question about the vertical stacking, which I think is the part that doesn't overlap with your other post.

Answer (score 2):

The vertical "stacks" correspond to frames; in other words, the pitch candidates are stacked vertically because Praat attempts to measure the "pitch" (actually fundamental frequency) at every frame. The horizontal placement of each stack corresponds to the occurrence of each successive frame over time, which is why they are equally spaced. The vertical placement of each candidate in the stack is dictated by its frequency (in Hz), as specified by the frequency axis on the right.

The numbers at the very top are not pitch candidates, but rather measures of relative intensity of the sound in each frame.

You can read more about the display of the PitchEditor on [this Praat help page](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/PitchEditor.html).

Comment: Thanks. So, is it correct to say that a vertical "stack" consists of several pitch candidates of different frequencies within a given frame. The largely the number of a candidate, the greater the intensity. So, in the example I gave, the most intense candidates formed the fundamental frequency identified by Praat. Is this correct?

Comment: @mateuz it depends on what you mean by "intensity". The digits at the top of the display (in your image the 5-4-4-4-4-4-4-4-3-3-3-2-2-2-3) express the relative intensity of the _overall sound_ at each frame. The pitch candidate numbers below are measures of "goodness", where how "goodness" is calculated depends on the algorithm Praat is set to use. This is explained on the help page I linked to above: "The number [...] may be the relative height of an autocorrelation peak, a cross-correlation peak, or a spectral peak, depending on the method by which the Pitch object was computed.